# Failed to set directory permission

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, rsync, file-permissions

I am trying to change the permission of a folder in a mounted hard drive.

I didn't use command line to mount (nautilus file manager mounted for me when I clicked on it).

After the drive was mounted, the permission looks like this:

```
$ ll /run/media/myuser/
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser  4096 Feb 16 09:27 XYZ
```

Then, I do

```
$ sudo ln -s /run/media/myuser/XYZ/myData /data
$ chown -R externaluser:externaluser /data
$ ll / | grep data
lrwxrwxrwx    1 externaluser externaluser    44 Mar  2 11:17 data -> /run/media/myuser/XYZ/myData
```

However, if I run

```
$ ll /run/media/myuser/XYZ | grep myData
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser     48 Mar  2 12:16 myData
```

The owner and group are still myuser even after I ran:

```
chown -R externaluser:externaluser /run/media/myuser/XYZ/myData
```

How can this be fixed?

Basically, I would like to give access of this folder only to an external user to `rsync` data to that folder but I don't want to give access to other folders in the same drive.

Thanks.

This is CentOS 7 if it matters.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski would you mind making it an answer?  I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The symlink (ln -s command) and the directory are two different entities with their own ownership and permissions.
If what you finally want is to give permission to externaluser to your real directory, you should write:

`sudo chown -R externaluser:externaluser /run/media/myuser/XYZ/myData`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my typo in my last command...I forgot to include `externaluser:externaluser` when I typed up my post (fixing...).  Tho, I actually included it and the ownership of the folder didn't get changed :(

Comment: please post the result of the following:
`stat /run/media/myuser/XYZ/myData;echo $?;stat /myData;echo $?`

Comment: Juan, thanks for trying to help.  As Kmail pointed out, it was because of how NTFS works.  Hence, I reformatted the HD and set it to xfs and now I can set the permission properly.  Thanks!